# $X_n \xrightarrow{p} X \Rightarrow \exists\hspace{0.2em} X_{n_j} \xrightarrow{a.s.}X$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

i need a check about this demonstration

suppose that $X_n \xrightarrow{p} X$ and take some decreasing $\{\epsilon_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ who satisfy $\epsilon_m\rightarrow0$ and define:

- $A_{j,\epsilon}= \{ \omega \in \Omega : \vert X_j(\omega)-X(\omega)\vert <\epsilon\}$
- $S_{n,\epsilon}= \bigcap_{j \geq n} A_{j,\epsilon}$
- $S_{\epsilon}=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}S_{n,\epsilon}=\liminf A_{j,\epsilon}$
- $S:= \bigcap_{m \in \mathbb{N}}S_{\epsilon_m}$

is easy to demonstrate that $S =\{ \omega \in \Omega: \lim_{j\to \infty}X_j(\omega) = X(\omega)\}  $

now fixing $m$ i can build an increasing $n : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$  who satisfy $$\mathbb{P}(\vert X_{n_j}-X\vert>\epsilon_m)\leq2^{-j}, \forall j\in \mathbb{N}$$

now because $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\vert X_{n_j}-X\vert>\epsilon_m)\leq\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}2^{-j}<\infty$, by borel-cantelli lemma

$$\mathbb{P}(\limsup A_{j,\epsilon_m})=0 \Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(S_{\epsilon_m})=1$$
so this demonstate that $\mathbb{P}(S_{\epsilon_m})=1$ do not depend by $m $

now $\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty}S_{\epsilon_m})=\lim_{m\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(S_{\epsilon_m})=1$, this is because $$\epsilon < \epsilon' \Rightarrow S_{\epsilon} \subset S_{\epsilon'} \Rightarrow S_{\epsilon_{m+1}}\subset S_{\epsilon_{m}}, \forall m \in \mathbb{N}$$

i think that all i used for demonstrate this theorem is legal

Comment: This is a pretty standard result. It seems like you are overcomplicating the notation and indexing. I just read the proof again to refresh, and it took me a few seconds to recall the details. This is somewhat confusing.

Comment: I'm sorry, i thought that the exposition could be better. 
my only doubt is about the correctness of $\mathbb{P}(S_{\epsilon_m})=1,\forall m \in \mathbb{N}$ i find it difficult to accept that it is constant